# add javascript programmatically

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm using the linkedin `JS-API`

This [example](http://bit.ly/eKjd0X)

I'm accepting the company name from the user. So, I want to build the `<script>` part of the above example programmatically. This is what I've done so far,

```
function companySearch()
{
   var companyName = document.getElementById("companyName").value;

   var searchHTML = "Search Results : ";


   searchHTML = searchHTML + "<p> The company details are as follows";
   searchHTML = searchHTML + "<script type=\"IN/CompanyProfile\" data-id=\"linkedin\" data-format=\"hover\"></script>";
   searchHTML = searchHTML + "</p>";

   document.getElementById("companyResult").innerHTML = searchHTML;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
    <script type="IN/Login"></script>
            <h1>
                LINKEDIN COMPANY SEARCH
            </h1>    

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Company Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="Text" id="companyName" value=""/>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Search LinkedIn" onclick="companySearch()"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>      


        <div id="companyResult">


        </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break up your script tags so the parser doesn't see them:

```
searchHTML = searchHTML + "<scr" + "ipt type=\"IN/CompanyProfile\" data-id=\"linkedin\" data-format=\"hover\"></scr" + "ipt>";
```

Comment: You sir, have saved my life & time, thank you. Appreciate it.