# Adding script src after window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, src

I'm trying to add this social widget after the body has loaded.

I first tried doing:

```
var stumble = '<script src="' + 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=1' + '">       <\/script>';
$('#social-widget').append(stumble);
```

But that obviously didn't work, so I tried:

```
var stumble = document.createElement('script');
stumble.src = 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=1';
$('#social-widget').append(stumble);
```

Which also didn't work. Any idea on what I am missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add javascript programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187413/add-javascript-programmatically)

Comment: @Diodeus Tried that method (breaking up the script tags so the parser won't recognize them), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=1** script only renders the button where it was placed and cannot work after document load.

instead use this script :

1/ place this tag where you want the button to appear

```
$('#social-widget').append('<su:badge layout="5"></su:badge>');
```

2/ load and execute the script :

```
jQuery.getScript('//platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method eg:

```
$.getScript('http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=1');
```

Comment: How would this insert the the button into the DOM after the page has loaded?

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily insert the script in the DOM, it would however load and execute the script, which I presumed is what you're after? Why else would you want to append a script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You should really try something cross-browser, and since you're trying to load the script asynchronously, I strongly recommend [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#setup). 
You can use is standalone or alongside libraries like jQuery or Dojo.